# How to add album art to mp3 using vlc media player in ubuntu?

Tags: music, banshee, vlc, mp3

I want to add **Album art** to any mp3 song. But I don't know how to do it.My system  has  **VLC media player**, **UMPlayer**, **Bashee media player**, **Movie player**. How can I add **Album art** to  mp3 file using  at least any one among those media player ?

A screenshot is given below:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to download anything, VLC works well with album art 'out of the box'.

Since it is unclear to me whether you are asking how to 
(1) manually add, or 
(2) automatically download, album art, I will answer both:

1. Manually Adding Album Art, or Downloading One Album Art
   Tools > Media Information (CTRL+I) > "General" Tab > 
   Right-click on the proxy (default) orange cone picture (1" x 1", on the bottom right) 
   > Select "Add cover art from file" or "Download cover art".

   > Change any value (e.g.: the Artist), only then the 'Save Metadata' button will appear, after it does - press it.

[image: manual art]

Performed on v2.1.4.

2. Automatically Downloading All Album Art
   Just go to "Tools"->"Preferences" menu. Under the "Interface" tab there is a "Privacy/Network Interaction" section. Under "Album art download policy" choose "As soon as track is added". See screenshot below.

This will download the album art for any song you play.

See screenshot below:

[image: auto art 1]

[image: auto art 2]

Answer (score 6):

Try using a tag-editing program like Easy Tag, which is provided by the `easytag` package in the official repositories.

Answer (score 5):

None among the apps you listed gives an option to add images to an audio file. You can install `puddletag`, which would give you an option to add image to any audio file.

[Install Puddletag](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/puddletag/)

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: It is not present in the **Ubuntu software center**

Comment: It seems to have been added in 12.04. You can add the webupd8 [Puddletag PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/puddletag) to get it or download it from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/puddletag/)

Comment: My system version is 11.04. Will this application support in it.

Comment: The PPA lists 11.04 (natty) as supported, so I'm pretty sure it would work.