# Can I make mp3's in one map one icon and in another map another icon

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, icons, mp3

What I want to do is give the mp3's the icon of the picture of the cd they are on. Example the mp3's in music/Meat Loaf/Bat out of Hell have the albumcover as icon and music/Queen/Greatest Hits have their icon. Both, of course, have different covers. But if I change the icon of the mp3's in one map, all mp3's get that icon. Is there a way to achieve what I want or is that impossible? I use Kubuntu 20.04.2.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918295/how-to-enable-ubuntu-kde-dolphin-to-preview-audio-thumbnails) help? Question is: do your mp3 files have an album cover?

Comment: You can do what you want  but not in the totally wrong way you're approaching it. MP3 files support metadata and that is what should be edited, NEVER the file properties! Here's some suggestions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/788954/how-to-add-id3-cover-art-by-command-line and https://askubuntu.com/questions/307666/how-to-add-album-art-to-mp3-using-vlc-media-player-in-ubuntu